# Apache camel, how to move message from SOAP to JMS

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, jms, integration

I'm learning Apache Camel framework, and try to build simple route where message is received from SOAP endpoint and is put into JMS queue (ActiveMQ).

I have the following route

```
<route id="cxfToJMSRoute">
    <from uri="cxf:bean:endpoint" />
    <log message="test" />
    <wireTap uri="direct:logInfo" />
    <to uri="activemq:queue:api" />
</route>
```

And the endpoint and queue are defined as follows

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="endpoint" address="http://localhost:1010/hello"
        serviceClass="net.webservicex.GlobalWeatherSoap" wsdlURL="META-INF/globalweather.wsdl" />

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://127.0.0.1:61616"/>
</bean>
```

However, when I call the endpoint, the other service reading the message queue throws following error

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.. Message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 8, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:IT-L-R90HKRNH-64004-1511880368329-1:1:2:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:IT-L-R90HKRNH-64004-1511880368329-1:1:2:1, destination = queue://api, transactionId = null, expiration = 1511880389430, timestamp = 1511880369430, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1511880369434, brokerOutTime = 1511880369495, correlationId = Camel-ID-IT-L-R90HKRNH-1511880338904-0-3, replyTo = temp-queue://ID:IT-L-R90HKRNH-64004-1511880368329-1:1:1, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@663a8b1b, marshalledProperties = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@504b2d9b, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 1640, properties = {SOAPAction=http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry, CamelHttpCharacterEncoding=UTF-8, User_HYPHEN_Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5), Host=127.0.0.1:1010, operationName=GetCitiesByCountry, operationNamespace=http://www.webserviceX.NET, breadcrumbId=ID-IT-L-R90HKRNH-1511880338904-0-1, Content_HYPHEN_Type=text/xml;charset=UTF-8, CamelHttpMethod=POST, accept_HYPHEN_encoding=gzip,deflate, connection=keep-alive, CamelHttpUri=/hello, CamelHttpPath=}, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false}
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractBodyFromJms(JmsBinding.java:160) ~[camel-jms-2.16.3.jar!/:2.16.3]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.createBody(JmsMessage.java:236) ~[camel-jms-2.16.3.jar!/:2.16.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:54) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$35.evaluate(ExpressionBuilder.java:905) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.builder.ExpressionBuilder$76.evaluate(ExpressionBuilder.java:1836) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.LogProcessor.process(LogProcessor.java:64) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112) ~[camel-jms-2.16.3.jar!/:2.16.3]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719) ~[spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679) ~[spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649) ~[spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) [spring-jms-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar!/:5.14.5]
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:208) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar!/:5.14.5]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractBodyFromJms(JmsBinding.java:135) ~[camel-jms-2.16.3.jar!/:2.16.3]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
        at org.apache.activemq.util.ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.checkSecurity(ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java:112) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar!/:5.14.5]
        at org.apache.activemq.util.ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java:57) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar!/:5.14.5]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.getObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:206) ~[activemq-client-5.14.5.jar!/:5.14.5]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
```

So do I have to convert the message to POJO myself before the JMS? I'm completely new to Camel, but I got the impression Camel should handle type conversions automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to send Java objects to a JMS broker, so instead you can convert the message to be text based via by adding

```
<convertBodyTo type="String"/>
<to uri="activemq:queue:api" />
```

Before sending to the JMS broker.

You may need to add camel-jaxb on the classpath to allow Camel to automatic convert your POJO class to text as XML. Or you can configure your SOAP endpoint to not use POJO type and just raw XML, then Camel can send that raw XML directly to JMS as text based.

Comment: So, is it implicitly a POJO which is returned by cxfEndpoint? Do I have to convert it back to POJO, when listening the MQ using camel in another service?